# Use version control for a live website

Tags: svn, git, version-control

I have a live website hosted in a linux shared godaddy account. I want to start using Version Control. I also have a easyPHP localhost in my windows, where I do my development and testing. I am looking at options of git and subversion

I want some general guidelines. Should I create a local repository? How to make this my actual local code, so to see what happens? How to synchronize with the webserver? Or just keep version control locally and ftp my code to the server? Need to create another repository there? Any help appreciated!

Comment: If you're lucky, I'll explain this in a blogpost.  These questions aren't a good fit for Serverfault, but they are a good fit for my blog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Select only one SCM for using. I'll **strongly do  not recommend** to have Git as first SCM, contrary to alternatives - Git will poison your mentality and make movement  to and learning of other SCMs a lot harder (big problem, which have not competitors)
2. Grok SCM of choice at least basic ideas (commits, repository, working directory, updates, history of changes...)
3. Differentiate tasks of code versioning and code distribution (while to some degree distribution can be performed using SCM methods), find useful for you tools
4. Try to do something

Return to SO later with new prepared power questions. Because now

- you can have local or remote repo (it's *your* choice)
- you can use SCM's hooks and scripting for deploy or deploy by hand (it's *your* choice)

Comment: @Badger. I don't really need to commit my changes directly to the server. I need to have a repository to commit my changes, and the server to be able to synchronize with these. What do you suggest?

Comment: thanks @Badger. I went with subversion in eclipse. with git i have bad experiences :)

Answer (score 0):

You can check out Bazaar http://bazaar.canonical.com/en/ they have GUI also , you can keep repository locally on your desktop and can also configure Phing to automate your Deployement
on server.